# Converting values with commas in a pandas dataframe to floats.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to convert values with commas in a pandas dataframe to floats with little success. I also tried .replace(",","") but it doesn't work? How can I go about changing the Close_y column to float and the Date column to date values so that I can plot them? Any help would be appreciated. [image: This is what I've tried]

Comment: If you loaded this data from a csv, [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) accepts `thousands` arg and `parse_dates`

Comment: I loaded it from clipboard..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert 'Date' using `to_datetime` for the other use `str.replace(',','.')` and then cast the type:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['Close_y'] = df['Close_y'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
```

`replace` looks for exact matches, what you're trying to do is replace any match in the string

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) implements the same kwargs as [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) in which there are options for the `thousands` and `parse_dates` kwarg.s

Try loading your data with:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(thousands=',', parse_dates=[0])
```

Assuming that the `Dates` column is in the 0 index. If you have a large amount of data you may also try using the `infer_datetime_format` kwarg to speed things up.

Comment: Thank you very much.. :)